# Centering figure on page

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I am new to Latex and trying to center two figures using the following script:

```
\begin{figure}

\begin{center}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale = 0.07,trim={40 5 25 10},clip]{Constantloadwithrigidboundary_Uy_X0Y0}}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale = 0.07,trim={40 5 25 10},clip]{Constantloadwithrigidboundary_Vy_X0Y0}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

As explained near the end of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1D-AWSLrJo) video. Unfortunately in my case the figures do not center but rather are skewed to the right of the page as shown below:[image]

I am also including the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
```

At the beginning of my script. Why does this happen? How can I get my subfloats to center properly on the page?

Comment: The problem arises because the combined width of your two images exceeds the `\textwidth` which you set aside for the document.  It thus spills out the right margin.  You could reduce the size of your figures, or you could expand the margins for this page.

Comment: Thats true. reducing the scale of the figures centered it. Another problem I didn't mention above is that the figure is thrown to the last page of my document (I have no idea why). How can I fix that? I need the figure to appear in my subsection of choice within the document....

Comment: I just figured it out. It is because I need to include the float package and set the figure parameter to [H]. This forces the figure to occur approximately where it does in the tex code. @Steven your answer is valid if you like you can post and I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is one of overflowing the allocated text width, as shown in the first figure set in the MWE below (where the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package shows explicitly the text area allocated by the current document settings).  TeX honors the left margin, but if the figure-set is too large, it spills out the right.

There are three fixes:

1. You can reduce the width of the figure-set to fit inside the margins allocated; this is the route taken in the 2nd figure-set on the 1st page.
2. You can trick LaTeX into momentarily ignoring the margins, as I do on page 2 of the MWE.  With `\makebox[0pt]{\begin{minipage}{1.2\textwidth}...\end{minipage}}`, I create a `minipage` large enough to handle the oversized figure-set, but then place it in a zero-width `\makebox` subject to `center`ing.  The `\makebox` thus makes TeX unaware that the `minipage` exceeds the margin bounds.  Note that I also use an `\hfill` to employ the full width of the `minipage`, lest the `minipage` be centered, but not its content.  Or, finally,
3. You can set a `\newgeometry` expanding the margins, possibly for a single page only (shown on pages 3,4 in MWE below).

The MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale = 0.45]{example-image-A}}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale = 0.45]{example-image-B}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale = 0.35]{example-image-A}}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale = 0.35]{example-image-B}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\makebox[0pt]{\begin{minipage}{1.2\textwidth}%
\subfloat{%
\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{example-image-A}}%
\hfill%
\subfloat{%
\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{example-image-B}}%
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\savegeometry{origigeom}
\clearpage
\newgeometry{margin=2cm}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\subfloat{%
\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{example-image-A}}%
\subfloat{%
\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{example-image-B}}%
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
Hi, Mom!
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]